# Проблема с FancyBox

Tags: jquery, html, php, css, javascript

Вечер добрый! 
Сделал форму для обратной связи с помощью FancyBox. При проверке в браузере все работает нормально. Но вот незадача, залил сайт в сеть и вместо корректно открывающегося окна с формой, открывается новая страница с этой формой, со стилями все ок, а вот сам эффект не срабатывает, т.е. как будто не видит этот плагин.

Тестовый вариант хостинга, для проверки- http://ce34418.tmweb.ru/index.htm

Comment: Ссылка на сайт?

Comment: Добавил ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас отсутствует файл на сервере: http://ce34418.tmweb.ru/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5

Соответственно он и не знает про такую функцию, как `.fancybox()`.

Не забывайте пользоваться консолью разработчика в браузере, там много полезного бывает написано.

Comment: Но у меня такого файла вообще нету...есть такой- jquery.fancybox.pack.js

Comment: У вас сбились ссылки на скрипты, не грузятся вообще все скрипты, возможно, раньше html лежал в той же папке, что и скрипты, теперь скрипты лежат в отдельной папке, поправьте пути в head.

Comment: http://ce34418.tmweb.ru/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js вот, кстати, ваш fancybox, а на сайте прописана ссылка 

    scr="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"

Comment: Просто странно, как так работает вне хостинга с теми же файлами, а в сети не хочет...

Comment: это я закинул еще в папку js, подумал, может быть, он оттуда заработает. Но я смотрю на сервере лежит файл jquery.fancybox.pack.js, в нужном месте... но не работает.

Comment: если ссылка на файл не работает, значит он лежит не в нужном месте, либо путь прописан неверно, нажмите ctrl+shift+i в chrome и увидите все битые ссылки

Comment: всем спасибо за помощь! Особенно за ctrl+shift+i, даже не пользовал честно говоря. Все оказалось банально...папку была названа funkyBox, изменил регистр букв на нижний- funkybox и вуаля)) 
Всем добра и успехов!